# Suspend work in VS 2013 gives error Parameter cannot be null: parentHierarchy

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When I try to suspend my work in Visual Studio 2013 it gives the following error:

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: parentHierarchy

I'm using an on premises TFS 2012 server and I was able to shelve the changes afterwards. What could cause this?

[image]

Comment: This error _still_ appears in Visual Studio 2017, thankfully [Exatex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25444784/1204599) still solves it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same issue with TFS 2013 / Vs 2013.
Fixed with Click on Save All command 
[image: Vs.Net 2013 Save All Command]

Comment: Me too. I guess we have to save our solution before we can suspend the current work

Comment: Applies to Visual Studio 2019 + Azure DevOps 2019 as well

Answer (score 3):

Reopening project solved problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Had this error in VS2013 using TFS2013. Somehow one file was present in the solution and VS thinking the file was already in TFS and couldn't handle a change to this file, resulting in the error mentioned above.

Solved it by deleting the file, checked-in the project, added the file to the project and checked in again.

Annoying bug.